# NetTopologySuite polygon is not valid

Tags: nettopologysuite

Can anyone tell me why when I load the following polygon into NetTopologySuite its not valid? When I load it the `IsValid` property is False

```
MULTIPOLYGON(((120.399269 16.46649, 120.397217 16.46594, 120.392883 16.465441, 120.392883 16.465441, 120.399269 16.46649)),((120.399269 16.46649, 120.397217 16.46594, 120.392883 16.465441, 120.392883 16.465441,120.390404 16.46488, 120.387833 16.464319, 120.384727 16.463869, 120.383537 16.463671, 120.381409 16.46279, 120.378967 16.462469, 120.370087 16.461109, 120.369217 16.46073, 120.362152 16.46007, 120.360489 16.4596, 120.357941 16.45927, 120.352203 16.45846, 120.349792 16.45793, 120.347672 16.457491, 120.34407 16.456631, 120.342133 16.456381, 120.340981 16.45598, 120.338417 16.45582, 120.336678 16.455641, 120.33474 16.45524, 120.331802 16.45492, 120.331718 16.455351, 120.331657 16.45607, 120.331657 16.45682, 120.331581 16.45755, 120.331383 16.458229, 120.331123 16.458879, 120.330841 16.46026, 120.330833 16.460979, 120.330803 16.461281, 120.330772 16.461691, 120.330597 16.462391, 120.330513 16.463131, 120.330322 16.463791, 120.330299 16.46386, 120.330078 16.46459, 120.330009 16.46537, 120.329987 16.46616, 120.329407 16.46911, 120.329163 16.46979, 120.329041 16.470091, 120.328613 16.471109, 120.328369 16.471769, 120.328201 16.472441, 120.328003 16.47307, 120.327667 16.47361, 120.327293 16.47411, 120.327049 16.47459, 120.326874 16.47517, 120.326172 16.47645, 120.326012 16.4771, 120.325813 16.47777, 120.325546 16.478411, 120.325287 16.47905, 120.32505 16.479691, 120.324738 16.480289, 120.324448 16.480921, 120.324173 16.48155, 120.324013 16.481899, 120.323883 16.48218, 120.323601 16.4828, 120.32338 16.483431, 120.323334 16.484091, 120.323334 16.48476, 120.32338 16.485411, 120.323486 16.486031, 120.323357 16.48662, 120.32309 16.487169, 120.322723 16.48765, 120.32225 16.48806, 120.322151 16.488159, 120.321793 16.488501, 120.321388 16.489019, 120.321022 16.489571, 120.320793 16.490219, 120.320602 16.4909, 120.320511 16.491619, 120.320267 16.49226, 120.319946 16.492849, 120.319656 16.49346, 120.319168 16.494169, 120.319099 16.494381, 120.318893 16.49472, 120.317299 16.49667, 120.316399 16.497499, 120.315697 16.49785, 120.315277 16.498119, 120.31472 16.498199, 120.313957 16.49847, 120.313332 16.49861, 120.312912 16.498819, 120.312553 16.49885, 120.311943 16.49889, 120.311394 16.49896, 120.309723 16.49931, 120.309448 16.49931, 120.308823 16.49889, 120.308693 16.49861, 120.309158 16.49806, 120.309578 16.497709, 120.31028 16.497231, 120.311241 16.497021, 120.311462 16.497089, 120.311882 16.497089, 120.312233 16.496941, 120.312233 16.496389, 120.312157 16.49604, 120.311943 16.49556, 120.311668 16.495279, 120.311111 16.495279, 120.310249 16.494989, 120.309937 16.495001, 120.309662 16.49501, 120.309402 16.495081, 120.308121 16.495001, 120.307838 16.495131, 120.307732 16.49514, 120.306961 16.49556, 120.306297 16.496071, 120.305496 16.496969, 120.305023 16.49773, 120.304817 16.498501, 120.304108 16.49966, 120.303864 16.500151, 120.303642 16.50065, 120.303497 16.501181, 120.303398 16.50173, 120.303436 16.5023, 120.303574 16.502871, 120.303612 16.503429, 120.304039 16.504391, 120.304352 16.505051, 120.304581 16.50563, 120.304733 16.506109, 120.305153 16.507351, 120.305527 16.50799, 120.305832 16.508329, 120.306007 16.50853, 120.306107 16.50865, 120.306252 16.50931, 120.306183 16.50959, 120.306137 16.50989, 120.306183 16.51041, 120.306534 16.511499, 120.306664 16.511669, 120.306938 16.51243, 120.30722 16.51306, 120.307503 16.51417, 120.30764 16.514799, 120.307777 16.51528, 120.307777 16.515829, 120.307503 16.51667, 120.307373 16.516809, 120.307137 16.517179, 120.307129 16.517891, 120.307564 16.51856, 120.307693 16.518761, 120.308067 16.51923, 120.308609 16.51972, 120.309448 16.520281, 120.309723 16.520281, 120.30983 16.520309, 120.309998 16.52035, 120.310417 16.520281, 120.311111 16.52, 120.311394 16.51993, 120.311668 16.51972, 120.31221 16.51959, 120.313057 16.51944, 120.314163 16.51944, 120.314919 16.51931, 120.315826 16.519171, 120.316933 16.518961, 120.31778 16.518749, 120.318047 16.518749, 120.319099 16.51833, 120.321243 16.518009, 120.32132 16.518, 120.3218 16.517929, 120.322632 16.51792, 120.323189 16.51778, 120.323891 16.51778, 120.32473 16.51757, 120.325546 16.51722, 120.325897 16.51708, 120.326111 16.51708, 120.326668 16.517, 120.327606 16.517139, 120.327827 16.51716, 120.328613 16.51722, 120.32917 16.51722, 120.329437 16.51722, 120.32972 16.51729, 120.32972 16.51741, 120.32972 16.51778, 120.329643 16.51786, 120.329437 16.518061, 120.329437 16.51833, 120.32917 16.51861, 120.328888 16.51861, 120.328613 16.51889, 120.328331 16.51889, 120.328056 16.519171, 120.327499 16.519171, 120.32711 16.51915, 120.326569 16.519211, 120.326073 16.519421, 120.325951 16.519461, 120.325546 16.519581, 120.324989 16.519699, 120.324379 16.519739, 120.323753 16.51993, 120.32309 16.52, 120.322456 16.520081, 120.321892 16.520309, 120.321358 16.520571, 120.320824 16.52083, 120.320251 16.521049, 120.319633 16.52117, 120.319069 16.521351, 120.318466 16.52146, 120.317886 16.52166, 120.317299 16.521851, 120.316658 16.52198, 120.316032 16.522181, 120.315392 16.522181, 120.314774 16.52202, 120.314117 16.521959, 120.313469 16.521971, 120.312866 16.52212, 120.312279 16.522249, 120.311707 16.5224, 120.311172 16.52257, 120.311012 16.52264, 120.310692 16.522791, 120.31028 16.523069, 120.309952 16.523411, 120.309761 16.523821, 120.309669 16.5243, 120.309723 16.524719, 120.310837 16.525829, 120.31118 16.52632, 120.31218 16.52784, 120.3125 16.52833, 120.312851 16.52882, 120.314377 16.530769, 120.314857 16.531469, 120.315353 16.53195, 120.315842 16.53236, 120.316467 16.53306, 120.316727 16.533409, 120.316948 16.533609, 120.317436 16.53466, 120.317513 16.535151, 120.317497 16.53631, 120.317627 16.5371, 120.317642 16.537149, 120.31778 16.53861, 120.318047 16.540001, 120.318336 16.54167, 120.318626 16.542231, 120.31884 16.542919, 120.318932 16.543659, 120.318977 16.543859, 120.319107 16.544411, 120.319199 16.54517, 120.319313 16.5459, 120.319397 16.546631, 120.31942 16.54734, 120.319321 16.54805, 120.319191 16.54875, 120.319054 16.54945, 120.319038 16.54952, 120.318932 16.550159, 120.318893 16.55089, 120.31884 16.551611, 120.318687 16.55229, 120.318817 16.55291, 120.318993 16.553511, 120.319138 16.55415, 120.319168 16.5548, 120.319199 16.5553, 120.319206 16.55545, 120.319359 16.556061, 120.31942 16.5567, 120.319443 16.557341, 120.319473 16.55798, 120.31958 16.558599, 120.31974 16.559191, 120.319946 16.55975, 120.32 16.560381, 120.32 16.561029, 120.320053 16.561661, 120.320236 16.56226, 120.320267 16.56287, 120.320282 16.563499, 120.320267 16.563971, 120.320267 16.564119, 120.320282 16.564739, 120.32032 16.56535, 120.320343 16.56543, 120.320511 16.565941, 120.320557 16.566561, 120.320557 16.567181, 120.320541 16.56781, 120.320457 16.56842, 120.320381 16.56904, 120.32029 16.56967, 120.320229 16.570299, 120.320053 16.57085, 120.32 16.57147, 120.32 16.572109, 120.32 16.572411, 120.32 16.57276, 120.319962 16.5734, 120.319748 16.574011, 120.319733 16.574089, 120.319603 16.574631, 120.319443 16.57522, 120.319267 16.5758, 120.319038 16.576309, 120.318687 16.576651, 120.31868 16.576691, 120.318237 16.577021, 120.317802 16.57728, 120.317368 16.577551, 120.31694 16.577829, 120.316498 16.578091, 120.316223 16.57839, 120.315773 16.578791, 120.315407 16.57913, 120.315033 16.579451, 120.314659 16.57979, 120.314293 16.580151, 120.313873 16.58046, 120.313423 16.580759, 120.312958 16.58107, 120.312447 16.581341, 120.311913 16.581539, 120.31134 16.58165, 120.310753 16.581671, 120.310158 16.581631, 120.309578 16.58143, 120.30909 16.58135, 120.309013 16.581341, 120.308601 16.58107, 120.308296 16.580681, 120.307968 16.580311, 120.307579 16.580021, 120.307121 16.57988, 120.306602 16.580021, 120.306091 16.58028, 120.305557 16.580509, 120.304947 16.580561, 120.304321 16.580561, 120.303703 16.580589, 120.303131 16.58075, 120.302559 16.5809, 120.302032 16.5811, 120.301521 16.581289, 120.301117 16.581579, 120.300758 16.581921, 120.300377 16.58223, 120.300034 16.582569, 120.299744 16.582951, 120.299507 16.583389, 120.299339 16.583879, 120.299202 16.584379, 120.299156 16.58497, 120.299171 16.585569, 120.299217 16.586149, 120.299423 16.58667, 120.299606 16.58717, 120.299767 16.58746, 120.29985 16.58762, 120.300117 16.588039, 120.300392 16.58847, 120.300636 16.588989, 120.300842 16.589569, 120.301048 16.59016, 120.301147 16.59078, 120.301338 16.591379, 120.301376 16.591999, 120.301392 16.59263, 120.301369 16.59326, 120.301262 16.59388, 120.30114 16.5945, 120.301109 16.59516, 120.301109 16.595539, 120.301109 16.595819, 120.301109 16.596491, 120.301071 16.59716, 120.30088 16.59779, 120.300789 16.59844, 120.300552 16.599001, 120.300293 16.59956, 120.300117 16.60009, 120.299927 16.600861, 120.29969 16.60144, 120.299309 16.60195, 120.298912 16.602449, 120.298569 16.60302, 120.29821 16.603571, 120.297813 16.60408, 120.297447 16.604469, 120.297371 16.604549, 120.29686 16.60495, 120.296333 16.60532, 120.295753 16.605659, 120.295082 16.605869, 120.294434 16.606159, 120.293747 16.6064, 120.293091 16.60664, 120.29248 16.606779, 120.291939 16.60638, 120.291397 16.605869, 120.29081 16.605431, 120.290161 16.60512, 120.289436 16.605009, 120.288727 16.605049, 120.288116 16.60531, 120.287643 16.6057, 120.287216 16.606079, 120.286774 16.60639, 120.286331 16.606689, 120.285927 16.60704, 120.285591 16.60747, 120.285294 16.607941, 120.285004 16.608419, 120.284737 16.60891, 120.284531 16.609421, 120.28447 16.609909, 120.28434 16.610331, 120.284264 16.61075, 120.284027 16.61128, 120.283707 16.61166, 120.283333 16.61199, 120.282944 16.61228, 120.282501 16.612511, 120.282082 16.61278, 120.28167 16.61305, 120.281273 16.61334, 120.280891 16.61363, 120.28051 16.61392, 120.280113 16.614201, 120.279762 16.61451, 120.279472 16.61487, 120.279259 16.61528, 120.279083 16.615721, 120.278908 16.61614, 120.278732 16.61655, 120.278481 16.616859, 120.278297 16.617229, 120.278038 16.617519, 120.277687 16.61772, 120.277779 16.618059, 120.277779 16.619169, 120.277496 16.61944, 120.277496 16.620831, 120.277748 16.62141, 120.277946 16.62187, 120.278107 16.62233, 120.278313 16.622761, 120.278503 16.623199, 120.278687 16.62359, 120.278816 16.6238, 120.278923 16.62397, 120.279182 16.62431, 120.279488 16.62462, 120.279846 16.62488, 120.280319 16.62504, 120.280792 16.62521, 120.281319 16.625271, 120.281868 16.625259, 120.282417 16.62517, 120.282944 16.624969, 120.283409 16.62468, 120.283813 16.6243, 120.284126 16.623871, 120.28437 16.62343, 120.284737 16.623051, 120.285179 16.6227, 120.285606 16.622311, 120.286057 16.621929, 120.286537 16.621559, 120.287163 16.62126, 120.287727 16.62089, 120.28833 16.620541, 120.288902 16.620119, 120.289467 16.619671, 120.289963 16.619169, 120.290421 16.61869, 120.290947 16.618299, 120.291542 16.617979, 120.291893 16.61763, 120.292084 16.6171, 120.292122 16.61643, 120.291878 16.61574, 120.291557 16.615061, 120.291458 16.614441, 120.29158 16.61384, 120.291557 16.61318, 120.291649 16.61273, 120.291779 16.612301, 120.292023 16.612129, 120.292084 16.61194, 120.292221 16.61167, 120.292297 16.611589, 120.292297 16.61138, 120.292374 16.61117, 120.292664 16.610889, 120.293068 16.610531, 120.293198 16.609989, 120.293472 16.60956, 120.293747 16.609631, 120.294449 16.609631, 120.294868 16.60957, 120.295067 16.609301, 120.295563 16.608891, 120.29583 16.60861, 120.296387 16.60861, 120.296944 16.608061, 120.297791 16.60807, 120.298058 16.60833, 120.298058 16.608891, 120.298889 16.60972, 120.299156 16.610001, 120.299721 16.610001, 120.300003 16.60972, 120.301941 16.60972, 120.302223 16.60944, 120.30278 16.60944, 120.303017 16.609699, 120.303047 16.60972, 120.303337 16.60972, 120.303612 16.610001, 120.303886 16.610001, 120.304169 16.610279, 120.304443 16.610279, 120.305 16.61083, 120.305267 16.61083, 120.305557 16.611111, 120.305962 16.61132, 120.306503 16.61154, 120.307007 16.611891, 120.307533 16.61223, 120.308006 16.612619, 120.308441 16.61307, 120.308853 16.61355, 120.30928 16.614, 120.309311 16.614031, 120.309723 16.61445, 120.31012 16.614969, 120.310577 16.61545, 120.311058 16.615931, 120.311493 16.61648, 120.311943 16.617001, 120.312187 16.617371, 120.312332 16.617559, 120.313423 16.61969, 120.31424 16.62129, 120.314613 16.62174, 120.31488 16.62229, 120.315033 16.622931, 120.315086 16.623131, 120.315239 16.623581, 120.315323 16.62413, 120.315338 16.62425, 120.315536 16.62484, 120.315712 16.625441, 120.315811 16.62587, 120.315857 16.62606, 120.316017 16.626499, 120.316078 16.62664, 120.316322 16.62719, 120.316589 16.627701, 120.316658 16.6283, 120.316589 16.62891, 120.316261 16.62945, 120.315872 16.629971, 120.31546 16.630461, 120.314919 16.630819, 120.314293 16.631069, 120.313568 16.63114, 120.312881 16.6313, 120.312263 16.631519, 120.311729 16.631861, 120.311607 16.63195, 120.311218 16.63224, 120.310738 16.63265, 120.31031 16.63311, 120.310013 16.633671, 120.309753 16.634279, 120.309532 16.634899, 120.309303 16.635481, 120.308937 16.63592, 120.308617 16.636379, 120.308327 16.636881, 120.308022 16.63735, 120.30764 16.63777, 120.307266 16.63817, 120.306999 16.638639, 120.307007 16.6392, 120.307251 16.639759, 120.307503 16.640329, 120.307732 16.640921, 120.307777 16.64155, 120.307777 16.6422, 120.307777 16.64286, 120.307777 16.643511, 120.307823 16.64414, 120.308029 16.644699, 120.308289 16.64522, 120.308609 16.645691, 120.308937 16.646151, 120.309334 16.646549, 120.309723 16.646959, 120.310066 16.647409, 120.310448 16.64784, 120.310806 16.648291, 120.311218 16.648689, 120.311707 16.649, 120.312263 16.64922, 120.312782 16.649481, 120.31324 16.649799, 120.313637 16.650181, 120.314049 16.65052, 120.314491 16.65081, 120.314957 16.651039, 120.315437 16.65119, 120.315887 16.651409, 120.316292 16.651661, 120.316566 16.651899, 120.316643 16.65196, 120.316856 16.65242, 120.317963 16.654449, 120.318207 16.654869, 120.318283 16.655069, 120.318382 16.655319, 120.318573 16.65576, 120.318657 16.65625, 120.318718 16.65638, 120.318863 16.656691, 120.319092 16.65712, 120.319427 16.657459, 120.319847 16.657721, 120.32032 16.65785, 120.320732 16.65811, 120.320938 16.658331, 120.321083 16.65847, 120.321327 16.65889, 120.321442 16.659401, 120.321609 16.65988, 120.321671 16.66037, 120.321693 16.6605, 120.321732 16.66082, 120.321938 16.661169, 120.322159 16.661489, 120.32235 16.661791, 120.322632 16.661921, 120.322952 16.66198, 120.323242 16.66214, 120.323853 16.66218, 120.324448 16.66222, 120.324722 16.6625, 120.325279 16.6625, 120.325279 16.662781, 120.325546 16.662781, 120.325844 16.663059, 120.325844 16.66333, 120.326668 16.664169, 120.328056 16.665001, 120.328888 16.665831, 120.329857 16.66642, 120.330276 16.66667, 120.330559 16.666941, 120.330559 16.667219, 120.33078 16.66745, 120.330833 16.6675, 120.330833 16.667681, 120.330833 16.66778, 120.331108 16.66806, 120.331108 16.668329, 120.331261 16.66889, 120.331749 16.66959, 120.331749 16.66993, 120.332024 16.670349, 120.332092 16.670771, 120.332573 16.67194, 120.332687 16.6721, 120.333168 16.672581, 120.333191 16.672609, 120.333557 16.67312, 120.333839 16.67375, 120.334038 16.67441, 120.334259 16.67503, 120.334633 16.67551, 120.33493 16.676029, 120.335228 16.67654, 120.335457 16.677111, 120.33551 16.677231, 120.335709 16.677679, 120.335739 16.67779, 120.335861 16.678169, 120.335892 16.67827, 120.336128 16.67885, 120.336189 16.67897, 120.336388 16.679411, 120.336487 16.679729, 120.336578 16.68, 120.336487 16.680651, 120.336456 16.681299, 120.33667 16.681931, 120.336899 16.68256, 120.337852 16.68453, 120.338127 16.688169, 120.338043 16.688801, 120.338074 16.689091, 120.338089 16.68939, 120.337837 16.68998, 120.337723 16.69066, 120.337486 16.691299, 120.337219 16.69194, 120.336922 16.69257, 120.336563 16.693119, 120.336189 16.693529, 120.335892 16.69393, 120.335617 16.69433, 120.33532 16.694639, 120.335297 16.694679, 120.335114 16.695009, 120.33493 16.695391, 120.334747 16.695761, 120.334709 16.696329, 120.335052 16.69693, 120.335281 16.69746, 120.33551 16.697981, 120.335663 16.698561, 120.335823 16.69912, 120.335953 16.699699, 120.336082 16.70027, 120.33622 16.70085, 120.33654 16.701309, 120.336708 16.70187, 120.336884 16.702431, 120.336937 16.703011, 120.33696 16.703621, 120.337029 16.70422, 120.337173 16.70483, 120.337212 16.705481, 120.337227 16.70615, 120.33728 16.7068, 120.337502 16.707411, 120.337723 16.70801, 120.337753 16.708639, 120.337646 16.70928, 120.337624 16.70948, 120.337532 16.709921, 120.337502 16.710569, 120.337486 16.71117, 120.337486 16.71121, 120.337471 16.71184, 120.337532 16.71253, 120.33757 16.71291, 120.338074 16.713461, 120.338593 16.71347, 120.339607 16.713301, 120.340134 16.713079, 120.340393 16.713169, 120.34111 16.712879, 120.341812 16.712549, 120.342506 16.71232, 120.343132 16.71237, 120.34333 16.712709, 120.343246 16.71311, 120.343246 16.713449, 120.342987 16.713579, 120.342621 16.713869, 120.342194 16.71419, 120.341759 16.71452, 120.34137 16.71489, 120.340973 16.71524, 120.340523 16.715521, 120.34005 16.71578, 120.339577 16.716021, 120.339432 16.71636, 120.339363 16.71653, 120.339203 16.716619, 120.338913 16.716921, 120.338837 16.717131, 120.338753 16.71747, 120.338837 16.718019, 120.33902 16.71855, 120.339256 16.719049, 120.339447 16.71958, 120.339622 16.7201, 120.339706 16.720659, 120.339767 16.72122, 120.339943 16.7216, 120.339973 16.721689, 120.340187 16.722151, 120.340317 16.72261, 120.340523 16.72303, 120.34063 16.723471, 120.34079 16.72385, 120.340897 16.72426, 120.341049 16.724661, 120.341118 16.725142, 120.34111 16.72559, 120.34111 16.72608, 120.34111 16.72658, 120.34111 16.727079, 120.34111 16.727579, 120.34111 16.7281, 120.341133 16.728609, 120.341217 16.72913, 120.341339 16.729639, 120.341316 16.73019, 120.34137 16.73074, 120.341377 16.7313, 120.341393 16.731871, 120.341393 16.73245, 120.341393 16.73304, 120.341377 16.733641, 120.341301 16.734221, 120.34108 16.734751, 120.340828 16.735279, 120.340584 16.73583, 120.340424 16.736441, 120.340347 16.73707, 120.340263 16.73769, 120.340088 16.738279, 120.339951 16.73888, 120.33963 16.739361, 120.33918 16.73967, 120.338608 16.739771, 120.338074 16.74, 120.33754 16.740219, 120.336922 16.740259, 120.336319 16.74032, 120.335777 16.740549, 120.335281 16.740841, 120.334846 16.74119, 120.334763 16.741301, 120.334602 16.74168, 120.334419 16.74221, 120.334213 16.74271, 120.334167 16.74325, 120.334297 16.743481, 120.334381 16.74365, 120.334419 16.74408, 120.33448 16.74435, 120.334534 16.74469, 120.334541 16.74505, 120.334801 16.745279, 120.33506 16.745461, 120.335327 16.74559, 120.335823 16.74575, 120.33593 16.74613, 120.336304 16.74649, 120.336281 16.746651, 120.336159 16.748091, 120.33638 16.748569, 120.336472 16.749029, 120.336197 16.74939, 120.335953 16.749809, 120.335663 16.750219, 120.335533 16.750771, 120.335419 16.751329, 120.335327 16.7519, 120.335281 16.75247, 120.335312 16.753031, 120.33548 16.75354, 120.335693 16.754021, 120.335907 16.754459, 120.336098 16.754919, 120.33625 16.75543, 120.336357 16.755951, 120.33638 16.75629, 120.336388 16.7565, 120.336418 16.757059, 120.336517 16.75761, 120.336617 16.75815, 120.336647 16.75869, 120.33667 16.759211, 120.336708 16.759701, 120.336868 16.760111, 120.337196 16.760509, 120.337303 16.760759, 120.33725 16.76108, 120.336617 16.76141, 120.336327 16.76185, 120.335876 16.762079, 120.335648 16.76263, 120.335342 16.76306, 120.335037 16.763451, 120.334831 16.763901, 120.334663 16.764339, 120.334389 16.76473, 120.334152 16.76511, 120.333893 16.76545, 120.333672 16.765791, 120.333519 16.76619, 120.333382 16.76646, 120.333344 16.766541, 120.333191 16.76687, 120.333183 16.767179, 120.332916 16.767469, 120.332718 16.76778, 120.332558 16.768299, 120.332314 16.768551, 120.331467 16.769171, 120.331329 16.769421, 120.331284 16.76951, 120.331146 16.769871, 120.331123 16.77013, 120.331093 16.770309, 120.330971 16.770769, 120.330963 16.771219, 120.331093 16.771561, 120.331017 16.772129, 120.331078 16.77269, 120.331177 16.773239, 120.331131 16.773809, 120.331078 16.77437, 120.331062 16.77494, 120.330849 16.775471, 120.330658 16.77603, 120.330521 16.776621, 120.330338 16.77721, 120.330338 16.777821, 120.330223 16.778111, 120.330994 16.77833, 120.334663 16.779631, 120.335876 16.780001, 120.338112 16.78055, 120.342529 16.78145, 120.346573 16.78186, 120.349121 16.782009, 120.350342 16.78249, 120.351593 16.782539, 120.352089 16.78257, 120.354057 16.78249, 120.357117 16.78211, 120.35865 16.782221, 120.359993 16.782351, 120.361443 16.782339, 120.364342 16.78212, 120.365509 16.78212, 120.366722 16.78212, 120.367989 16.78227, 120.370506 16.78252, 120.381371 16.779289, 120.38385 16.77939, 120.386467 16.77844, 120.388771 16.77774, 120.392853 16.776251, 120.394562 16.775181, 120.39698 16.774071, 120.399521 16.77248, 120.402161 16.771219, 120.404907 16.76931, 120.408447 16.766581, 120.412163 16.76343, 120.425003 16.753349, 120.426537 16.75322, 120.431427 16.75028, 120.434174 16.748791, 120.439018 16.745831, 120.455093 16.737329, 120.475212 16.728149, 120.481232 16.72439, 120.484779 16.72274, 120.486687 16.72183, 120.489258 16.720869, 120.492683 16.719521, 120.500237 16.71641, 120.5028 16.714701, 120.50631 16.713921, 120.508812 16.712601, 120.509407 16.71229, 120.511627 16.711241, 120.513908 16.71084, 120.515991 16.710329, 120.519989 16.7101, 120.523201 16.709669, 120.524811 16.709471, 120.527267 16.70899, 120.530327 16.708139, 120.53302 16.70731, 120.535789 16.707081, 120.540802 16.70579, 120.541962 16.702749, 120.542282 16.700529, 120.542442 16.698811, 120.543167 16.697121, 120.545486 16.695761, 120.54744 16.69454, 120.5494 16.69356, 120.551353 16.69293, 120.553177 16.69207, 120.555946 16.69055, 120.557114 16.68964, 120.558167 16.688351, 120.559357 16.687599, 120.560402 16.68648, 120.561371 16.684481, 120.561577 16.68273, 120.561684 16.68153, 120.561371 16.679529, 120.560349 16.677481, 120.560333 16.67523, 120.561157 16.67127, 120.562263 16.6703, 120.564247 16.67063, 120.566101 16.671181, 120.567299 16.67156, 120.56855 16.671869, 120.570213 16.67174, 120.57135 16.67074, 120.572273 16.66884, 120.574341 16.66461, 120.576477 16.6621, 120.577927 16.66077, 120.579681 16.65971, 120.580437 16.659241, 120.576813 16.65213, 120.563148 16.63092, 120.541893 16.60751, 120.537514 16.611549, 120.527679 16.618231, 120.520683 16.623791, 120.51326 16.628719, 120.505592 16.631081, 120.499191 16.630171, 120.49511 16.632669, 120.489502 16.63835, 120.483871 16.639771, 120.480293 16.63973, 120.475372 16.64151, 120.469528 16.64341, 120.46563 16.64467, 120.46312 16.646561, 120.459023 16.64992, 120.45211 16.65346, 120.447243 16.655121, 120.443604 16.655569, 120.443527 16.65398, 120.442352 16.652781, 120.443413 16.649309, 120.444122 16.64596, 120.442062 16.64337, 120.442429 16.63928, 120.44075 16.635481, 120.441093 16.62834, 120.44162 16.61318, 120.436737 16.612579, 120.437576 16.60556, 120.437027 16.59494, 120.438919 16.5937, 120.441063 16.59263, 120.443481 16.591669, 120.444397 16.589371, 120.44593 16.586981, 120.447449 16.585119, 120.449982 16.583349, 120.452606 16.580839, 120.461617 16.57711, 120.463707 16.5734, 120.464363 16.571569, 120.464973 16.56793, 120.46302 16.56535, 120.460983 16.56365, 120.460297 16.56332, 120.459053 16.56286, 120.457771 16.562401, 120.456657 16.56127, 120.45562 16.56074, 120.454742 16.56041, 120.454231 16.56007, 120.453682 16.558981, 120.453293 16.557659, 120.45356 16.556681, 120.453194 16.55525, 120.452309 16.55368, 120.452026 16.55275, 120.451729 16.552311, 120.450821 16.551439, 120.450233 16.549681, 120.450851 16.54887, 120.450867 16.54863, 120.450844 16.547331, 120.4496 16.54611, 120.448509 16.54607, 120.447662 16.545099, 120.447273 16.54427, 120.446693 16.54236, 120.446449 16.541401, 120.446129 16.53966, 120.445618 16.538811, 120.444641 16.537729, 120.444099 16.53684, 120.444313 16.535839, 120.445091 16.53574, 120.446388 16.53603, 120.447762 16.53558, 120.448227 16.53508, 120.447868 16.534189, 120.445793 16.533661, 120.444901 16.533461, 120.443542 16.53327, 120.443024 16.533039, 120.442574 16.53231, 120.442451 16.53137, 120.442627 16.530371, 120.444153 16.52977, 120.442078 16.528549, 120.442299 16.523331, 120.441994 16.52235, 120.442947 16.521351, 120.443733 16.5208, 120.444054 16.520121, 120.444107 16.519239, 120.443428 16.51889, 120.442413 16.51922, 120.441071 16.51943, 120.440041 16.5194, 120.44046 16.51689, 120.441383 16.51605, 120.442574 16.515881, 120.443108 16.515511, 120.443291 16.515209, 120.443352 16.514851, 120.443298 16.51403, 120.443573 16.513069, 120.442993 16.51281, 120.442558 16.51244, 120.441971 16.511921, 120.442139 16.51029, 120.44236 16.50985, 120.442581 16.509371, 120.442886 16.508591, 120.442612 16.50832, 120.442047 16.50794, 120.441322 16.507311, 120.440697 16.506809, 120.440552 16.506121, 120.44059 16.50572, 120.441063 16.504589, 120.441681 16.503981, 120.442139 16.503839, 120.442421 16.50382, 120.443443 16.503969, 120.444023 16.504141, 120.444702 16.504311, 120.444946 16.504049, 120.444977 16.503811, 120.44455 16.50304, 120.444221 16.502609, 120.442993 16.50131, 120.443077 16.50116, 120.443047 16.50028, 120.443153 16.4995, 120.443649 16.499161, 120.444359 16.499121, 120.444717 16.49931, 120.445038 16.49971, 120.445312 16.499781, 120.445778 16.499519, 120.446297 16.49873, 120.446404 16.49798, 120.44622 16.49671, 120.446098 16.49601, 120.446037 16.495081, 120.446136 16.4946, 120.446579 16.493679, 120.4468 16.492571, 120.447052 16.491249, 120.447166 16.49045, 120.447243 16.490089, 120.447433 16.489309, 120.447929 16.488991, 120.449043 16.488461, 120.449692 16.48793, 120.450592 16.4867, 120.452766 16.48205, 120.454514 16.479111, 120.454323 16.477501, 120.454338 16.47435, 120.455406 16.472281, 120.454498 16.46903, 120.454109 16.465969, 120.454224 16.46314, 120.455177 16.46055, 120.456306 16.459101, 120.457764 16.45668, 120.459648 16.45446, 120.455917 16.449051, 120.450417 16.4471, 120.445717 16.448219, 120.442978 16.448009, 120.441078 16.44916, 120.439957 16.453529, 120.434959 16.45573, 120.431137 16.46035, 120.428253 16.462299, 120.424896 16.46386, 120.420464 16.462111, 120.419212 16.464661, 120.416031 16.46645, 120.413651 16.468479, 120.410004 16.469021, 120.408089 16.46784, 120.402733 16.467871, 120.401878 16.467661, 120.400002 16.466801, 120.399269 16.46649)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I paste it in to QGIS using the `QuickWKT` plugin and run the `QGIS geoalgorithms->Vector geometry tools->Check Validity` it says you have a duplicate point at `120.392883 16.465441` and looking there indicates that you do.

```
120.392883 16.465441, 120.392883 16.465441
```

Comment: Thank you very much. that was the problem. I wish NetTopologySuite would have told me that instead of only have a boolean.

Answer (score 2):

Just as additional information, you can use `TestBuilder` tool from [JTS Topology Suite](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jts-topo-suite/) for such verifications:

[image]